# Is this an error from book <Introduction to the Theory of Computation>?

Tags: finite-automata, dfa, nfa

The book <[Introduction to the Theory of Computation](https://books.google.com/books?id=1aMKAAAAQBAJ)>(3rd), described a NFA:

[image]

Then feed input '010110' to this NFA, the book gave this tree which I think is wrong:

[image]

The second input symbol '0' goes 3 branches which are q1,q2,q3. But q3 branch is not supposed to present according the description of this NFA.

Comment: There is an empty transition from q2 to q3 (the epsilon) so it's always possible to get to q3 when you get to q2

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I mean when the NFA read the second symbol '1' (which is the first '1' in '010110', [left to right]).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum the first symbol in '010110' is '0', the second symbol in '010110' is '1', got it?

Comment: Right but what the epsilon means is that the automaton can move there without reading any letter. I'm not sure why sipser likes that notation but you better get used to it since he uses it throughout the book.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think I got it, the epsilon can let the state continue going to q3 from q2, right?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum would you please answer the question? I will accept it, will help for the people who has same questions like me. Thank you.